# Android OpenGL ES add object on touch

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch, coordinates

I am building a small Android application which will add a cube on user's touch. The z depth is always -10, screen is always in landscape mode. This question seems to be asked many times, but I cannot get it running, forgive me as I am newbie to opengl. 
I am quite confused about the screen coordinate/window coordinate/object coordinate to use with the gluUnproject. As I understand, screen is when user touch and we get x and y from motion even. Window coordinate is when we load the identity, and object coordinate is when we transform the identity matrix to get object's coordinate. Is that right?

And here is my code, the matrix stacking is from android api sample. Please point out what I am doing wrong.

---

The drawing part:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    for (GLObject glObject : list) {
        if (glObject != null) {
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glObject.draw(gl);
        }
    }
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    if (isTouching) {
        boolean addObject = false;
        for (GLObject glObject : list) {
            addObject = glObject.checkTouch(gl, x, y);
        }
        if (!addObject) {
            i++;
            Log.d("i", i + "");
            addGLObject(gl);
        }
        isTouching = false;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the code for adding object

```
private void getMatrix(GL10 gl, int mode, float[] mat) {
    GLView.matrixTrackingGL.glMatrixMode(mode);
    GLView.matrixTrackingGL.getMatrix(mat, 0);
}
public void addGLObject(GL10 gl) {
    float[] XY = getWorldCoordinate(gl, x, y);

    if (XY != null) {
//          XY[0] = (float) (x - Main.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) / 10;
//
//          XY[1] = (float) (Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - y) / 10;

        GLObject glObject = new GLObject(colors, XY[0], XY[1]);
        Log.d("Object position", "X: " + XY[0] + " Y: " + XY[1]);
        list.add(glObject);
    }
}
private float[] getWorldCoordinate(GL10 gl, int x, int y) {
    float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
    float[] projMatrix = new float[16];
    int[] viewport = {0, 0, Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT};


    getMatrix(gl, GL10.GL_MODELVIEW, modelMatrix);
    getMatrix(gl, GL10.GL_PROJECTION, projMatrix);

    float[] output = new float[4];
    GLU.gluUnProject(x, viewport[1] + viewport[3] - y, -10, modelMatrix, 0, projMatrix, 0, viewport, 0, output, 0);
    return new float[] {output[0]/output[3], output[1]/output[3]};
}
```

---

```
public class GLObject {
    private float[] vertices = { 1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f,
    -1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f,
    -1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f,
    1.000000f, -1.000001f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f,
    1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, };
private short[] faces = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5, 0, 4, 5, 0,
    5, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3, 4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 7 };
private float[] colors;
private float[] rot = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
private Float positionX, positionY;
private int alpha = 0;

// Our vertex buffer.
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

// Our index buffer.
private ShortBuffer faceBuffer;

public GLObject() {
    init();
}

public GLObject(float[] colors, float x, float y) {
    this.colors = colors.clone();
    this.positionX = x;
    this.positionY = y;

    if (positionX.intValue() % 2 == 0) {
        rot[0] = 1.0f;
    } else {
        if (positionY.intValue() % 2 == 0) {
    rot[1] = 1.0f;
    } else {
        rot[2] = 1.0f;
    }
    }
    init();
}

private void init() {
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(faces.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    faceBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    faceBuffer.put(faces);
    faceBuffer.position(0);
}

public boolean checkTouch(GL10 gl, int x, int y) {
    boolean isTouched = false;
    ByteBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

    gl.glReadPixels(x, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT - y, 1, 1, GL10.GL_RGBA,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    Log.d("COLOR",
            pixels.get(0) + " " + pixels.get(1) + " " + pixels.get(2) + " "
                    + pixels.get(3));
            // isTouched always false to test always add object to screen
    return isTouched;
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // OpenGL docs
    // Enable face culling.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // OpenGL docs
    // What faces to remove with the face culling.
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); // OpenGL docs

    // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
    // rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);// OpenGL docs.
    // Enable color
    gl.glColor4f(colors[0], colors[1], colors[2], 1.0f);
    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(positionX, positionY, -10);
    // rotate
    alpha += 1;
    gl.glRotatef(alpha, rot[0], rot[1], rot[2]);
    // draw
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, // OpenGL docs
            vertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, faces.length,// OpenGL docs
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, faceBuffer);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // OpenGL docs
    // Disable face culling.
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // OpenGL docs
}
```

}

---

onDraw:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | // OpenGL docs.
                GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        // Reset the projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 90.0f, Main.SCREEN_WIDTH/Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT, 3.0f, 100.0f); 
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 4.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    
        // draw object
        glObjectManager.draw(gl);
    }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having, and can you provide the implementation of GLObject?

Comment: @NickLH My problem is when I touch the screen, the object is added but not to the point I touch. They always added really near each other but I don't know where i did it wrong, since I am not good at math and new to OpenGl. The code for GLObject I added as above. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The fact that it is added at the wrong place may be due to your z coordinate being -10. I can't tell since you didn't post that part of the code, but if you are using a projection matrix (which I assume you are), then your boxes will not show up at the specified point due to the perspective projection.

Try using an ortho projection or printing the x and y coordinates to see if the position you are clicking and the position that the object creation happens is correct.

Comment: @NickLH I added the onDraw method, and to be more specified, my screen is always at landscape mode. When I draw an object, I translate it to (x, y, -10) (code in GLObject draw function) and the next object will load the identity matrix and continue to draw.

Comment: It has nothing to do with landscape mode, the problem is that you are translating your cube by -10 on the z axis. Try putting values of -100 and all the cubes will be at the center. Then try putting 0 for the z value (x, y, 0). The cubes will be much further out from the center of the screen and closer to where you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with landscape mode, the problem is that you are translating your cube by -10 on the z axis. Try putting values of -100 and all the cubes will be at the center. Then try putting 0 for the z value (x, y, 0). The cubes will be much further out from the center of the screen and closer to where you expect them to be.

Look at http://tle.tafevc.com.au/toolbox/file/9495cce8-17b5-a8a5-d9b3-47c0c142d88d/1/sketches_and_drawings_lo.zip/3204a_20_reading_drawings/images/brick_perspective.jpg for an example of perspective projection. When the cube is at z=0, that is what is in the image. But when z=-10, it is closer to the center of the screen (the X) and smaller, because it follows the blue lines out to the horizon.

Comment: I found the problem was with the gluunproject. If I replace z with 1 (not -10), the output array I receive will be like (0.3..., 0.2..., 1, 0.01...) which if I get output[0]/(output[3]*10) will return the correct point. Since this is quite ridiculous, I will read more about it. Thx for your help, will mark ur answer answerd :D